# Passing char pointer as argument to function

Tags: c

This porgram prints different permutations of a string.It works correctly if I declare string as char array in main and pass array name in printAnagram function.But if I declare string as
char* s = "hello" and pass 's' then it crashes. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void printAnagram(char *str, int b, int e);

int main()
{
    char *s = "ABC"; // works fine when char s[] = "ABC" is used.
    printAnagram(s, 0, 2);
    return 0;
}

void swap(char *a, char* b)
{
    char temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
void printAnagram(char *str, int b, int e)
{
    int i = 0;
    if(b==e)
        printf("%s\n", str);
    else
    {
        for(i=b;i<=e;i++)
        {
            swap((str+b),(str+i));
            printAnagram(str, b+1, e);
            swap((str+b), (str+i));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `char *s = "ABC";` - `"ABC"` is a string literal modifying it is UB.

Pointers are usually used to point to data that already exists, so you can use it like this

```
char arr[] = "C__";

char* t = &arr[0];
```

Also modifiable,

```
t[1] = 'p';

t[2] = 'p';
```

Here

```
char *t= "C__";
```

points to a *string constant*.

There is a better way of writing the above:

```
const char* t= "C__";
```

Comment: @Sadique I try this approach and when I send the char* t to the function, the arr[] does not change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The crash has to do with the kind of memory where the characters of your string are stored, not with whether or not you declare it as a character array or a pointer. In other words, you can keep the pointer, and copy the string into it, like this:

```
int main()
{
    char *s = strdup("ABC");
    printAnagram(s, 0, 2);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

C standard considers memory allocated to string literals, such as `"ABC"`, non-writable. Hence, any changes you do to them cause undefined behavior. When you change declaration to an array, C copies the literal into writable memory, so there is no undefined behavior (and no crash).

Answer (score 1):

`char *s = "ABC";` is a string literal stored in `read only memory` location. When you try modifying it, yes it will crash. In fact it is of `const char *s`. Instead you should be using as mentioned already as,

```
char s[] = "ABC";
```

Look at this previous SO answer [Modifying a string literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172075/segmentation-fault-reversing-a-string-literal).

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the read only memory.

```
char *a="ABC";// It will stored in the read only memory.
```

If you are trying to access this you cannot do.  You can use like this.

```
char array[]="ABC";
char *a=array;
```

Comment: no he doesn't have to allocate dynamically. Initializing an automatic array is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to declare a char array, for example `char [6] str="ABC";` and then use a char pointer, to manage that array: `char *p=&str;`
The crash is due to the fact that your pointer to a string that is not present in the stack memory.