# What is the reason for segmentation fault in void reverse(char*)?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I run this code, I am getting segmentation fault.
How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *str)
{
    char *end=str;
    char temp;
    while(*end)
    {
    ++end;
    }
    --end;

    while(str < end)
    {
        temp=*str;
        *str=*end;
        *end=temp;
        str++;
        end--;
    }
}

void main()
{
    char *s="random";
    reverse(s);
}
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to learn a debugger, such that you master those kind of problems on your own.

Comment: Numerous duplicates, e.g. [Why is this string reversal C code causing a segmentation fault?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-string-reversal-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault) and [Segmentation fault reversing a string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172075/segmentation-fault-reversing-a-string-literal)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to reverse  constant value. Now that's not possible. Because you are trying to change a portion of read-only memory.

> **Solution**: Just use `char s[]="random";`

Previous case: s is pointing to the constant "random".

In this case: s is pointing to a local copy of the string literal "random" which is in stack memory.