# Remove spaces from string doesn't return anything

Tags: c

This code removes spaces from a string.

```
char *RemoveSpaces(char *source)
{  
    char* i = source;
    char* j = source;
    while(*j != '\0')
    {
        *i = *j++;
        if(*i != ' ')
            i++;
    }
    *i = 0;
    return i;
}
```

But when I use `printf` it doesn't return anything.

```
printf("%s", RemoveSpaces("HELLO WORLD!!! COME ONE\r"));
```

Comment: You might also be interested in [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3172075/898348)

Comment: You never remove any spaces. Check if it is a space _before_ you copy, not after.

Comment: @Lundin It removes the space by **not** incrementing `i` when the char is a space. The logic is a bit backwards but it works.

Comment: @4386427 Right, but it is needlessly inefficient. Copy first and verify after is a big no-no in general.

Answer (score 2):

```
*i = 0;
return i;   // wrong pointer returned
```

is wrong. It returns a pointer to the string termination (i.e. a pointer to the 0). Therefore it prints nothing.

Try:

```
*i = 0;            // or *i = '\0';
return source;     // correct pointer returned
```

Further, modifying a string literal is not allowed. Instead do:

```
char str[] = "HELLO WORLD!!! COME ONE\r";
printf("%s", RemoveSpaces(str));
```

Comment: Inside my code i'm using char with pointer. So i cant use a char array for this

Comment: @Dim Yes you can... When you pass an array to a function it decays into a pointer.

Comment: I cant understand why i can't pass *pointer in my method and i need to use char array.

Comment: @Dim As I wrote above: The code pass a pointer because an array decays into a pointer. If you prefer you can instead write: `char str[] = "HELLO WORLD!!! COME ONE\r"; char *pointer_to_string = str; 
printf("%s", RemoveSpaces(pointer_to_string));` It'll give the same result

Answer (score 1):

A slight adjustment to your space removal logic may help things make more sense. Instead of setting

```
    *i = *j++;
    if(*i != ' ')
        i++;
```

before you test whether `*i != ' '`, you may find it makes more sense to test first and then assign (where `p` is your `i` and `ep` (end pointer) is your `j`), e.g.

```
    while (*ep) {           /* iterate ep from beginning to end of src */
        if (*ep != ' ')     /* if its not a space */
            *p++ = *ep;     /* set begin pointer to char at end ptr, advance */
        ep++;               /* advance to next char */
    }
    *p = 0;                 /* nul-terminate src at p */
```

In that sense, you only assign and advance the initial pointer if the current character is not a space.

In your example and here, you are modifying the content of `source` in place, your `'i'` and `'j'` pointers are used for iterating over the characters in `source`, so when you are done with the iterations, you `return source` (or source can be used back in the caller without the return as you are modifying the contents of `source` in-place.

Putting those pieces together, you could do something similar like the following that will take the string to remove spaces from as the first argument to your code (or use `"HELLO WORLD!!! COME ONE\n"` by default if no argument is given), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *rmspaces (char *src)
{
    char *p = src,          /* pointer to beginning of src */
        *ep = src;          /* pointer to iterate to the end of src */

    while (*ep) {           /* iterate ep from beginning to end of src */
        if (*ep != ' ')     /* if its not a space */
            *p++ = *ep;     /* set begin pointer to char at end ptr, advance */
        ep++;               /* advance to next char */
    }
    *p = 0;                 /* nul-terminate src at p */

    return src;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char *s = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : (char[]){"HELLO WORLD!!! COME ONE\n"};
    printf ("%s", rmspaces (s));

    return 0;
}
```

(**Note:**, your editing in-place is fine, but `source` (or `src`) in my case must be modifiable, meaning you cannot pass a *string-literal* as `source` (which would likely SegFault). Above a *compound-literal* is used in the default case to insure the test past is a modifiable character array)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/rmspaces
HELLOWORLD!!!COMEONE
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.